# c# google calendar prevent CRUD on created events in google calendar via api

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, crud

I am building a calendar that needs to sync to google calendar. I wane know if the events that i created in my own calendar can't be changed in google calendar app. is it possible to block people from changing events in google calendar that i have created in my own agenda app. if people wane do a crud they need to use the app instead of google.

Comment: only the owner of an event can make changes.

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Do you want to prevent users from changing events on their personal calendars that they created through the app or events that are on the app's calendar? By default events can only be changed by the owner unless you change their permissions.

Comment: @Daniel i would like to prevent users to change thing in there google calender that are been made by the user in my application. what you ment (Do you want to prevent users from changing events on their personal calendars that they created through the app)